# c# mvc validation text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have edit bar for gender and i want to valid it (Male or Female), there is my model class:

```
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int BranchID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string SirName { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Gender  { get; set; }
```

and here is my view part i want to valid:

```
       <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
       </div>
```

Comment: First of all `Gender` should be `RadioButton Group`, for that use `Enum`. And then make it `Required`, thats it.

Comment: i search for it but can't find, can you show me the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an enum

```
public enum Gender
{
  Male,
  Female,
}
```

and in model change the property to

```
public Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

and in the view use radio buttons for the property

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male", new { id = "Gender_Male" })
<label for="Gender_Male">Male</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female", new { id = "Gender_Female" })
<label for="Gender_Female">Female</label>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
```